# "too few argument lists for macro invocation"

Tags: scala, scala-macros

Given the following code:

```
case class JetDim(dimension: Int) {
  require(dimension > 0)
}

object JetDim {
  def build(dimension: Int): Int = macro JetDimMacro.apply
}
```

and the macro that it calls:

```
def apply(dimension: Int): Int = macro applyImpl

def applyImpl(c: Context)(dimension: c.Expr[Int]): c.Expr[Int] = ...
```

I'm getting this compile-time error:

```
[error]  too few argument lists for macro invocation
[error]  def build(dimension: Int): Int = macro JetDimMacro.apply
```

Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `macro` keyword takes a method that should have a `Context` parameter as its first parameter list (and then however many `Expr` arguments in subsequent lists). In `JetDim` you're giving `macro` a method that itself has a macro implementation. This just isn't valid syntax—you can't "nest" `macro` like this. You'll need to either call `JetDimMacro.apply` directly (as a normal method call) in `JetDim.build`, or use `macro JetDimMacro.applyImpl` (which is more likely what you want).

Comment: Thanks, Travis. I was trying to following the model of your blog [post](https://meta.plasm.us/posts/2013/10/03/natural-vampires/). What's the difference in your post and my failed attempt (from the question)?

Comment: @KevinMeredith I probably won't have time to respond in detail until tomorrow at the earliest—sorry, it's a busy week.